# evaluate string expression in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have the following string expression which am trying to run ,But am getting error saying string format is not correct

```
for (i = diffvol; i < result.count; i++)
{
    B1Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("result.Data[0].B{0}Volume", i));
    B2Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("result.Data[0].B{0}Volume", i));
}
```

Comment: `result.Data[0].B{0}Volume` => even this is not a valid decimal format... you need to convert expression directly into decimal.

Comment: Supposing i==10 what should be the conversion to decimal of this string _result.Data[0].B10Volume_ ?

Comment: What you are getting in `result.Data[0]`?

Comment: @Steve yes it will be Data[0].B10Volume

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal called with a string expects to have a string that is the text rapresentation of a number, e.g. 10.25. The string you are passing is code that you expect will be evaluated: it will not.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is related to the Convert.ToDecimal method, NOT the String.Format. The reason should be obvious: a string such as "result.Data[0].B0" is not the string representation of a number. A string such as "1407" would be one.